# Averaging values at same position in List

Tags: scala

The following code averages the values at same position within an array:

```
  val toadd = List(Array(8.0, 4.0), Array(5.0, 8.0), Array(7.0, 5.0))
  val a1 = toadd.map(m => m(0)).sum
  val a2 = toadd.map(m => m(1)).sum     
  (a1/toadd.size , a2/toadd.size)
```

Currently this just works for arrays of length 2.

How can this be modified so that it works for arrays of arbitrary length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `transpose`:

```
toadd.transpose.map(xs => xs.sum / xs.size)
// List(6.666666666666667, 5.666666666666667)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of using `transpose`, as suggested by dhg.  If you wanted to use more primitive functions, you could do:

```
toadd reduce { 
    (x, y) => (x zip y) map { 
         case (a, b) => a + b 
    } 
} map { a => a / toadd.length }
```

Or more concisely:

```
toadd.reduce(_.zip(_).map(a=>a._1+a._2)).map(_/toadd.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like

```
val innerSize = toadd.map(_.length).min
```

and then map from `0 until innerSize` instead of doing it manually with `a1`, `a2`, etc..